# Having a problem with free function in C?

Tags: c, cs50, free, undefined-behavior, double-free

I am a beginner at coding and have a problem with my code. please advice.

Input:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int *list = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

   list[0] = 1;
   list[1] = 2;
   list[2] = 3;

   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       printf("%i\n", list[i]);
   }

    int *tmp = realloc(list, 4 * sizeof(int));
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        free(list);
        return 1;
    }

    free(list);

    tmp[3] = 4;

    list = tmp;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", list[i]);
    }

    free(tmp);
}
```

Output:-

```
1
2
3
1628405245
5
-136327152
4
```

I am having a problem with `free(list);` if i **remove** it, then the code seems to work fine,

but if i do this **(Which is done in CS50's lecture)**

```
tmp[3] = 4;

free(list);
```

Then the error comes

```
1
2
3
1508201014
5
1428381712
21918
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
zsh: abort      ./list1
```

**Why is this please Explain?**

Comment: You are not allowed to do this: `free(list);`. (I don't mean the lin where you handle the `NULL` case) Either `realloc` returned the same address as you provided to it, then you free your only memory and are not allowed to access it any longer afterwards. Of `realloc` returned a different address, then the old address does not belong to you any more and you are not allowed to free it again.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ok, so i don't need to free it, right?

Comment: Correct. You still free it later. But you should use `free(list)` instead of `free(tmp)` to avoid confusion.

Comment: @WhozCraig Ok, I understood.

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah, I did catch that error and corrected it. Thanks man

Comment: Replace the `free(list)` with `list=tmp;` then at the end `free(list)` not `tmp`.

Comment: from the  description of realloc : "On success, returns the pointer to the beginning of newly allocated memory. To avoid a memory leak, the returned pointer must be deallocated with free() or realloc(). The original pointer ptr is invalidated and any access to it is undefined behavior (even if reallocation was in-place)."

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard (7.22.3.5 The realloc function)

> 2 **The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by
> ptr** and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size
> specified by size.

and

> 3. ...If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is
>    not deallocated and its value is unchanged.

Thus the last call of free in this code snippet

```
int *tmp = realloc(list, 4 * sizeof(int));
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    free(list);
    return 1;
}

free(list);
```

invokes undefined behavior because the memory for the old object pointed to by the pointer list was already freed in this successful call of realloc

```
int *tmp = realloc(list, 4 * sizeof(int));
```

You need to remove the last call of free in this code snippet.

Also in this code snippet

```
tmp[3] = 4;

free(list);
```

the call of free invokes undefined behavior by the same reason.

Pay attention to that realloc can return the same address of the reallocated memory or a new address of the reallocated memory. This can influence on the result of undefined behavior.